# C# Hide/minimized the window with one more window using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, window

In C# I am trying to hide/minimize window. I am using selenium libraries here.
I tried searching in google but seems there is no way in that.

Is their any way I can create one more window which will hide the already opened window and display like "Page is loading" or "Wait for the Page". When the data loaded on the back window , the first window will close.

Please suggest some solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Minimise the window of what? The browser? Why? What difference does it make?

Comment: @Arran Minimize the window of already opened IE as that window is showing all steps through which I am navigating the page to the last report page. So I need to just display the last page of report and hiding the rest of things from user